# Not able to view the datasets while creating the charts

Tags: spagobi

I'm able to create the dataset and view it in the list of datasets. But, while creating the charts i'm not able to select the dataset in Document Details page. It's showing "server refused the connection". Can any one help in resolving this issue?

Thanks:
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and asked to the contact email. This was the answer:

> maybe due to a mistake on spagobi_host_url config: see 
>   [http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/DataViz_-*SpagoBI*-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Installation_from_released_package](http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/DataViz_-_SpagoBI_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Installation_from_released_package)
>   for details.

So I changed spagobi_host_url in conf/server.xml file to my server IP address instead of localhost and problem was fixed.

Hope this helps you.